# Get the code of a page generated with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to get the code of an URL page after it JavaScript executed.
For the exemple :

```
<?php
    function getVideoURL($link){
        $data = file_get_contents($link);
        print($data);
    }

    $link = htmlentities($_POST["link"]);

    getVideoURL($link);
?>
```

But this code give me the code of the url before javasript execution, is there a way to get it after javascript execution ?

Comment: your html and java script code

Comment: It is completely unclear what you ask. A URL _always_ points to a resource published by some server. Javascript _is part of that resource_, so delivered with the client. Only there it is interpreted. So there simply is not "URL to the resource with the script already executed". So it might be a good idea that you describe what you actually want to do, not how you think it might be done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

file_get_contents get the original code of the page, it doesn't execute any client side code ( javascript )

To execute javascript you will need an entire browser emulation engine -- a headless browser.

http://jonnnnyw.github.io/php-phantomjs/

```
use JonnyW\PhantomJs\Client;

function getVideoURL($link){
    $client = Client::getInstance();

    $request = $client->getMessageFactory()->createRequest($link, 'GET');

    $response = $client->getMessageFactory()->createResponse();

    $client->send($request, $response);

    if($response->getStatus() === 200) {

        // Dump the requested page content
        return $response->getContent();
    } else {
        return false;
    }

}

$link = htmlentities($_POST["link"]);

getVideoURL($link);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, it looks to be what i need, can yo help me in a private discuss how to use it ? It crashed at this line : $client->send($request, $response);

Comment: Did you install all the required scripts + phantomjs ? also , turn on full errors and notifications to see what causes the crash ( http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php )

Comment: I added this line and it don't change anything : error_reporting(E_ALL); I installed phantomjs with this method : http://jonnnnyw.github.io/php-phantomjs/installation.html need i anything else ?

Comment: define "crashed" .. what errors did you get? is there anything in the logs ? how did you know it crashed there?